# ASP .NET MVC - script reference inside partial view loaded by jQuery Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Ok. I have this code to load my form:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Board/Post/QuickEditPost",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#quick-edit-content').html(data);
        }
    });
    $('#quick-edit-dialog').dialog('open');
```

It's working fine. Form is loaded, I can edit my post and so on.
But to make it fully functional I need:

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        theme: "advanced",
        height: "450",
        width: "600",
        mode: "textareas"
    });
```

Which is not loaded into jQueryUI dialog.
And my question is why is not loaded and how to overrride this behavior.I tried to put those references in head section, but that's not an real option, I need then in few specific places over entire application. Not to mention it doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you include `jquery.js` before all other scripts? Shouldn't `tiny_mce.js` loaded before `jquery.tinymce.js` ?

Comment: Point is that those script do not load at all, when I check current DOM in firebug.

Comment: But they are within the response (network tab) in firebug? Check the network tab to see if there is a request to these scripts.

Comment: I Net tam after click link, seems like they are loading. But I still don't understrand, why they are not showing in current DOM.
Load order is good. I have exactly same on other pages and it's working fine.

Comment: Simply debug with an `alert()` or `console.log()` and see if your script block is evaluated, which should be the case.

Comment: alert is working fine. Oh Guess I have to do more investigation with script loading.

Comment: Be sure to not load jquery again at a later point. All plugins would be wiped.

Comment: @ŁukaszBaran Did you fix this ?